# Want REGEXP string which not allow 0 as first character and not allow 011, means any thing starting with 0 which is not allow

Tags: mysql, regex

I am running a mysql procedure in which my input parameter is `user_id`, I want to validate this `user_id`.

Condtion is `user_id` not start with 0 but it will contain 0 i.e 101 is valid input but 011 is not an valid input.

I write following code which allow 011 as valid code.

```
user_id REGEXP '^-?[^0]$|^[1-9]+[0-9]*$'
```

Can some one help me to correct my above code?

I want REGEXP which not allow 0 as first character and which not allow 011 or 01 or 000 but it allow 100 or 101.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^[^0][0-9]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YZ4ntZ8ppvlNoXVz)

Comment: Please any one give me solution as soon as possible, Thanks

Comment: The regex works for me. Added a demo link to my answer.

Comment: Thanks For this demo, this code is working when I give 01 in quote i.e '01' but when I give 01 without quote it allow 01 as user_id. I have to check my input parameter datatypes before running this code. Thanks For Help

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I used word boundary anchors that should work in mySQL, but your regex flavor may be different

To merely exclude zero as the first character, but ensure that it is still a digit:

```
 [[:<:]][1-9][[:digit:]]*[[:>:]]
```

To also ensure that a zero exists within the string:

```
 [[:<:]][1-9][0-9]*0*[0-9]*[[:>:]]
```